# Temporary disable console output for boost::log

Tags: c++, logging, boost

I added sink to file via `boost::log::add_file_log` and console output via `boost::log::add_console_log`. I am calling a logger via `BOOST_LOG_SEV` and everything workds perfectely. But there is a place, where a want output only to the file.

How I can disable cosole output in certain place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this with attributes and filters. For example, you could set up a filter in your console sink to suppress any log records that have (or don't have, depending on your preference) a particular attribute value attached.

```
boost::log::add_console_log
(
    ...
    boost::log::keywords::filter = !boost::log::expressions::has_attr("NoConsole")
    ...
);
```

Then you could set this attribute in the code region that shouldn't output logs in the console. For example, you could use a scoped attribute:

```
BOOST_LOG_SCOPED_THREAD_ATTR("NoConsole", true);
BOOST_LOG(logger) << "No console output";
```

You can use whatever method of setting the attribute - as a thread-local attribute, or a logger-specific, it doesn't matter.

The important difference from temporarily removing the sink is that the solution with attributes will not affect other threads that may be logging while you're suspending console output.

Comment: Thanks alot! This is a much cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can easely do it with `remove_sink()` function.

```
console_sink = boost::log::add_console_log(std::cout);
boost::log::core::get()->remove_sink(console_sink);
```

After that you can call an `add_console_log()` again and enable console output.